# How do I find the series' formula knowing its generating function: $f(x) = \frac{x}{6x^2-5x+1}$

Tags: power-series

$f(x) = \frac{x}{6x^2-5x+1}$ is the generating function of a series. How do I go about finding the formula of this series?

I started by finding the partial fractions: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2x-1} + \frac{-1}{3x-1}$$ How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Hint: Use $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$$

Comment: Once your denominators are linear terms, you can use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-r} = 1+r+r^2+\cdots$. So for example in this case, $\frac{1}{2x-1} = -\frac{1}{1-2x} = -(1+2x+(2x)^2+\cdots)$ and $-\frac{1}{3x-1} = \frac{1}{1-3x} = 1+3x+(3x)^2+\cdots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

As recomended, by Leon,

If $ |X|<1 $, then

$$\frac {1}{1-X}=1+X+X^2+...=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}X^k$$

So, if $ |3x|<1 $,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-3x}-\frac{1}{1-2x}=$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}((3x)^k-(2x)^k)$$

Comment: Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but would that mean, that the series I'm looking for is $a_{k} = \frac{(3x)^k - (2x)^k}{x^k}$ ?

Comment: @bosendorfer It is $ \sum (3^k-2^k)x^k$

Comment: How so? According to Wikipedia generating function formula is: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cdot x^n$$ So my generating function $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (3x)^k - (2x)^k$ doesn't exactly fit the Wikipedia's formula for generating function. Until, that is, I change the $(3x)^k-(2x)^k$ to $\frac{(3x)^k-(2x)^k}{x^k} \cdot x^k$. How is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Here, your $ a_n $ will be simply $ 3^n-2^n$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now. Thank you. I have one more question regarding your initial answer: if $|3x|\geq 1$ would it be possible to solve this task?

Comment: @bosendorfer This condition is equivalent $ -1/3<x<1/3$. I gives the Radius of convergence of the power series.